# Drive 8 Stepper motor simultaneous with different motion?

Tags: arduino, driver, stepper-motor, control

I have the need to drive 8 stepper motor together and with different motion behavior for each. Could I just get away with 8 stepper control board (easy driver) + an Arduino with enough pin to get the STEP/DIR from each driver and orchestrate all those motor with a nice code.

Or is there more thing to take in consideration ? More advance driver, or more powerful uC ?

Thanks in advance for any tips/suggestions.

Cheers,

Comment: Your proposed approach seems fine to me. The details of the application, motors, drivers, and "nice code" not being given, I am not sure if much more can be said about this at the moment. There may be more elegant, cheaper, or smaller approaches to this, but your initial idea is probably the easiest to get working if none of these factors are that important to you.

Comment: each motor are winding / unwinding a rope attached to an object (2Kg). The object have to have a course of +/- 1m. I should be able to control each motor with its own amplitude, speed, and also more behavior like acceleration and such ... This operation needs to be done for every motor separately. For the "nice code", I'm thinking of using OSC control over Ethernet/Wifi, that I would be able use a website based GUI to control the motion pattern of the motors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the L6470 which are a little pricy but worth it. Although a little work on coding at the beginning is needed, it will save you lots of hard work synchronizing all your motors to work with one another and enable you to use a cheaper MCU.